# How to browse and get only json position 0 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following json output.

```
"detections": [
  {
    "source": "detection",
    "uuid": "50594028",
    "detectionTime": "2022-03-27T06:50:56Z",
    "ingestionTime": "2022-03-27T07:04:50Z",
    "filters": [
      {
        "id": "F2058",
        "unique_id": "3638f7c0",
        "level": "critical",
        "name": "Possible Right-To-Left Override Attack",
        "description": "Possible Right-To-Left Override Detected in the Filename",
        "tactics": [
          "TA0005"
        ],
        "techniques": [
          "T1036.002"
        ],
        "highlightedObjects": [
          {
            "field": "fileName",
            "type": "filename",
            "value": [
              "1465940311.,S=473394(NONAMEFL(Z00057-PI‮fdp.exe))"
            ]
          },
          {
            "field": "filePathName",
            "type": "fullpath",
            "value": "/exports/10_19/mail/12/91/20193/new/1465940311.,S=473394(NONAMEFL(Z00057-PI‮fdp.exe))"
          },
          {
            "field": "malName",
            "type": "detection_name",
            "value": "HEUR_RLOTRICK.A"
          },
          {
            "field": "actResult",
            "type": "text",
            "value": [
              "Passed"
            ]
          },
          {
            "field": "scanType",
            "type": "text",
            "value": "REALTIME"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "F2140",
        "unique_id": "5a313874",
        "level": "medium",
        "name": "Malicious Software",
        "description": "A malicious software was detected on an endpoint.",
        "tactics": [],
        "techniques": [],
        "highlightedObjects": [
          {
            "field": "fileName",
            "type": "filename",
            "value": [
              "1465940311.,S=473394(NONAMEFL(Z00057-PI‮fdp.exe))"
            ]
          },
          {
            "field": "filePathName",
            "type": "fullpath",
            "value": "/exports/10_19/mail/12/91/rs001291-excluido-20193/new/1465940311.,S=473394(NONAMEFL(Z00057-PI‮fdp.exe))"
          },
          {
            "field": "malName",
            "type": "detection_name",
            "value": "HEUR_RLOTRICK.A"
          },
          {
            "field": "actResult",
            "type": "text",
            "value": [
              "Passed"
            ]
          },
          {
            "field": "scanType",
            "type": "text",
            "value": "REALTIME"
          },
          {
            "field": "endpointIp",
            "type": "ip",
            "value": [
              "xxx.xxx.xxx"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "entityType": "endpoint",
    "entityName": "xxx(xxx.xxx.xxx)",
    "endpoint": {
      "name": "xxx",
      "guid": "d1dd7e61",
      "ips": [
        "2xx.xxx.xxx"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Inside the 'filters' offset it brings me two levels, one critical and one medim, both with the variable 'name'.
I want to print only the first name, but when I print the 'name', it returns both names:
[image]

How do I print only the first one?
If I put print in for `filters`, it returns both names:
[image]

If I put print in for `detections`, it only returns the second 'name' and that's not what I want:
[image]

Comment: What's the purpose of the loop `j`? Why not use `i['filters'][0]['name']`?

Comment: The purpose is because I didn't know how to use this technique lol.
But now I've learned and I'm going to remodel the code to make it easier.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to print the name of the first filter, why iterate over it, just index it and print the value under "name":

```
for d in r['detections']:
    print(d['filters'][0]['name'])
```